# Почему трек добавляется, но не играет?

Tags: python, discord, youtube

Код на музыку:

```
# Silence useless bug reports messages
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


class VoiceError(Exception):
    pass


class YTDLError(Exception):
    pass

# ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    YTDL_OPTIONS = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'extractaudio': True,
        'audioformat': 'mp3',
        'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'ignoreerrors': False,
        'logtostderr': False,
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',
    }

    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
        'before_options':
        '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
        'options': '-vn',
    }

    ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YTDL_OPTIONS)


    def __init__(self,
                 ctx: commands.Context,
                 source: discord.FFmpegPCMAudio,
                 *,
                 data: dict,
                 volume: float = 0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.requester = ctx.author
        self.channel = ctx.channel
        self.data = data

        self.uploader = data.get('uploader')
        self.uploader_url = data.get('uploader_url')
        date = data.get('upload_date')
        self.upload_date = date[6:8] + '.' + date[4:6] + '.' + date[0:4]
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.thumbnail = data.get('thumbnail')
        self.description = data.get('description')
        self.duration = self.parse_duration(int(data.get('duration')))
        self.tags = data.get('tags')
        self.url = data.get('webpage_url')
        self.views = data.get('view_count')
        self.likes = data.get('like_count')
        self.dislikes = data.get('dislike_count')
        self.stream_url = data.get('url')

    def __str__(self):
        return '**{0.title}**'.format(self)

    @classmethod
    async def create_source(cls,
                            ctx: commands.Context,
                            search: str,
                            *,
                            loop: asyncio.BaseEventLoop = None):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        partial = functools.partial(cls.ytdl.extract_info,
                                    search,
                                    download=False,
                                    process=False)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)

        if data is None:
            raise YTDLError('Ошибка поиска: `{}`'.format(search))

        if 'entries' not in data:
            process_info = data
        else:
            process_info = None
            for entry in data['entries']:
                if entry:
                    process_info = entry
                    break

            if process_info is None:
                raise YTDLError('Ошибка поиска: `{}`'.format(search))

        webpage_url = process_info['webpage_url']
        partial = functools.partial(cls.ytdl.extract_info,
                                    webpage_url,
                                    download=False)
        processed_info = await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)

        if processed_info is None:
            raise YTDLError('Ошибка: `{}`'.format(webpage_url))

        if 'entries' not in processed_info:
            info = processed_info
        else:
            info = None
            while info is None:
                try:
                    info = processed_info['entries'].pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    raise YTDLError('Ошибка поиска: `{}`'.format(webpage_url))

        return cls(ctx,
                   discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(info['url'], **cls.FFMPEG_OPTIONS),
                   data=info)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_duration(duration: int):
        minutes, seconds = divmod(duration, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)

        duration = []
        if days > 0:
            duration.append('{} days'.format(days))
        if hours > 0:
            duration.append('{} hours'.format(hours))
        if minutes > 0:
            duration.append('{} minutes'.format(minutes))
        if seconds > 0:
            duration.append('{} seconds'.format(seconds))

        return ', '.join(duration)


class Song:
    __slots__ = ('source', 'requester')

    def __init__(self, source: YTDLSource):
        self.source = source
        self.requester = source.requester

    def create_embed(self):
        embed = (discord.Embed(
            title='Сейчас играет',
            description='[**{0.source.title}**]({0.source.url})'.format(self),
            color=discord.Color.blurple()).set_thumbnail(
                url=self.source.thumbnail))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Произошло это в {datetime.datetime.now()}")

        return embed

    def now_name(self):
            # title='Сейчас играет',
            # description='[**{0.source.title}**]({0.source.url})'.format(self),
            # color=discord.Color.blurple().set_thumbnail(
            #     url=self.source.thumbnail)
        now = self.source.url
        return now


class SongQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            return list(
                itertools.islice(self._queue, item.start, item.stop,
                                 item.step))
        else:
            return self._queue[item]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._queue.__iter__()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.qsize()

    def clear(self):
        self._queue.clear()

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self._queue)

    def remove(self, index: int):
        del self._queue[index]


class VoiceState:
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot, ctx: commands.Context):
        self.bot = bot
        self._ctx = ctx

        self.current = None
        self.voice = None
        self.next = asyncio.Event()
        self.songs = SongQueue()

        self._loop = False
        self._volume = 0.5
        self.skip_votes = set()

        self.audio_player = bot.loop.create_task(self.audio_player_task())

    def __del__(self):
        self.audio_player.cancel()

    @property
    def loop(self):
        return self._loop

    @loop.setter
    def loop(self, value: bool):
        self._loop = value

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self._volume

    @volume.setter
    def volume(self, value: float):
        self._volume = value

    @property
    def is_playing(self):
        return self.voice and self.current

    async def audio_player_task(self):
        while True:
            self.next.clear()

            if not self.loop:
                # Try to get the next song within 3 minutes.
                # If no song will be added to the queue in time,
                # the player will disconnect due to performance
                # reasons.
                try:
                    async with timeout(180):  # 3 minutes
                        self.current = await self.songs.get()
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    self.bot.loop.create_task(self.stop())
                    return

            self.current.source.volume = self._volume
            self.voice.play(self.current.source, after=self.play_next_song)
            emojico = ["<:2625applemusic:944531620617142292>","<:2870music:944531617882468402>","<:3567pigstep:944531620206084118>","<:7469noteblock:944531621858643999>","<:8066youtubemusic:944531622085140500>","<:6834radio:944531618482253835>"]
            msg = await self.current.source.channel.send(
                embed=self.current.create_embed())

            await msg.add_reaction(random.choice(emojico))

            await self.next.wait()

    def play_next_song(self, error=None):
        if error:
            raise VoiceError(str(error))

        self.next.set()

    def skip(self):
        self.skip_votes.clear()

        if self.is_playing:
            self.voice.stop()

    async def stop(self):
        self.songs.clear()

        if self.voice:
            await self.voice.disconnect()
            self.voice = None

    async def queue_clear(self):
        self.songs.clear()


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.voice_states = {}
        self.now_names = {}

    def get_voice_state(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        state = self.voice_states.get(ctx.guild.id)
        if not state:
            state = VoiceState(self.bot, ctx)
            self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id] = state

        return state

    def cog_unload(self):
        for state in self.voice_states.values():
            self.bot.loop.create_task(state.stop())

    def cog_check(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if not ctx.guild:
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage(
                'Эта команда не используется в ЛС (Личные сообщения)')


        return True

    async def cog_before_invoke(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        ctx.voice_state = self.get_voice_state(ctx)

    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
        await ctx.send('Ошибка: {}'.format(str(error)))

    @commands.command(name='join', invoke_without_subcommand=True)
    async def _join(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Подключается к голосовому каналу."""

        destination = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_state.voice:
            await ctx.voice_state.voice.move_to(destination)
            return

        ctx.voice_state.voice = await destination.connect()


    @commands.command(name='leave', aliases=['disconnect'])
    async def _leave(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Очистить очередь и заставить бота уйти."""

        if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
            return await ctx.send('Бот и так не подключен. Зачем его кикать?')

        await ctx.voice_state.stop()
        await ctx.send('Пока!')
        del self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id]


    @commands.command(name='volume')
    async def _volume(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, volume = None):
        """Изменить громкость. Возможные значения(0-200)"""

        if not volume:
            return await ctx.reply('Использование команды:\n`mwb!volume <Значение от 5-200>`')

        try:
            volume = int(volume)

        except ValueError:
            return await ctx.reply(f'Эта команда вызвала исключение/ошибку: {volume} - Это не число!')

        if not ctx.voice_state.is_playing:
            return await ctx.send('Сейчас музыка не играет. Можете включить.')

        if 0 > volume > 100:
            return await ctx.send('Volume must be between 0 and 100')

        ctx.voice_state.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send('Громкость изменена на {}%, введите mwb!re'.format(volume))

    @commands.command(name='np', aliases=['now playing', 'playing'])
    async def _now(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        """Увидеть, какая песня играет прямо сейчас"""

        if not ctx.voice_state.is_playing:
            return await ctx.reply('Сейчас музыка просто не играет. Можешь включить.')

        await ctx.send(embed=ctx.voice_state.current.create_embed())

    @commands.command(name='skip', aliases=["next"])
    async def _skip(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        if not ctx.voice_state.is_playing:
            return await ctx.send('Сейчас музыка не играет,зачем её пропускать? Можете включить.')

        if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
            await ctx.invoke(self._join)

        if (ctx.voice_state.current.requester):
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('⏭')
            ctx.voice_state.skip()

    @commands.command(name='queue')
    async def _queue(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, page: int = 1):
        if len(ctx.voice_state.songs) == 0:
            return await ctx.send('В очереди нет треков. Можете добавить.')

        items_per_page = 10
        pages = math.ceil(len(ctx.voice_state.songs) / items_per_page)

        start = (page - 1) * items_per_page
        end = start + items_per_page

        queue = ''
        for i, song in enumerate(ctx.voice_state.songs[start:end], start=start):
            queue += '`{0}.` [**{1.source.title}**]({1.source.url})\n'.format(i + 1, song)

        embed = (discord.Embed(description='**{} tracks:**\n\n{}'.format(len(ctx.voice_state.songs), queue))
                    .set_footer(text='Viewing page {}/{}'.format(page, pages)))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='shuffle')
    async def _shuffle(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        if len(ctx.voice_state.songs) == 0:
            return await ctx.send('В очереди нет треков. Можете добавить.')

        ctx.voice_state.songs.shuffle()
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')

    @commands.command(name='remove')
    async def _remove(self, ctx: commands.Context, index = None):

        try:
            index = int(index)

        except ValueError:
            return await ctx.reply(f'Эта команда вызвала исключение/ошибку: {index} - Это не индекс!')

        if not index:
            return await ctx.reply('Использование команды:\n`mwb!remove <Индекс>`')

        if len(ctx.voice_state.songs) == 0:
            return await ctx.send('В очереди нет треков. Можете добавить.')

        ctx.voice_state.songs.remove(index - 1)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')

    @commands.command(name='play', aliases=['p','add'])
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str = None):

            if not search:
                return await ctx.reply('Использование команды:\n`mwb!play <Ссылка, или название>`')

            if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                await ctx.invoke(self._join)

            msg = await ctx.reply(f'Подождите минуту...')
            try:
                source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx,
                                                        search,
                                                        loop=self.bot.loop)
            except YTDLError as e:
                await ctx.send('Ошибка: {}'.format(str(e)))
            else:
                song = Song(source)

                await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
                await msg.edit(content=f'Добавлено {source}')

    @commands.command(name='play-count')
    async def _playcount(self, ctx: commands.Context, count=1, *, search: str = None):

            if not search:
                return await ctx.reply('Использование команды:\n`mwb!play-count <кол-во> <что добавить?>`')

            if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                await ctx.invoke(self._join)
            
            msg = await ctx.reply(f'Подождите минуту...')
            
            for n in range(0, int(count)):

                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx,
                                                            search,
                                                            loop=self.bot.loop)
                except YTDLError as e:
                    await ctx.send('Ошибка: {}'.format(str(e)))
                else:
                    song = Song(source)

                    await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
            
            await msg.edit(content=f'Добавлено {source}')

    @commands.command(name="re", aliases=["replay"])
    async def _re(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if not ctx.voice_state.is_playing:
            return await ctx.reply('Сейчас музыка не играет,зачем её реплеить? Можете включить.')

        msg = await ctx.reply(f'Подождите минуту...')
        try:
            source2 = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx,
                                                    ctx.voice_state.current.now_name(),
                                                    loop=self.bot.loop)
        except YTDLError as e:
            await ctx.send('Ошибка: {}'.format(str(e)))
        else:
            song2 = Song(source2)

            await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song2)
            ctx.voice_state.skip()
            await msg.edit(content=f'<:b654094678543279e1ff53713c1d65e7:939828694577471538>')

    @commands.command(name="24/7")
    async def _whileplay(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                await ctx.invoke(self._join)

        msg = await ctx.reply(f'Подождите минуту...')
        try:
            source2 = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx,
                                                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21qNxnCS8WU",
                                                    loop=self.bot.loop)
        except YTDLError as e:
            await ctx.send('Ошибка: {}'.format(str(e)))
        else:
            song2 = Song(source2)

            await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song2)
            ctx.voice_state.skip()
            await msg.edit(content=f'<:b654094678543279e1ff53713c1d65e7:939828694577471538>')

    @_join.before_invoke
    @_play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice_state(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        if not ctx.author.voice or not ctx.author.voice.channel:
            raise commands.CommandError('Может ты сначала подключишься к голосовому каналу?')

        if ctx.voice_client:
            if ctx.voice_client.channel != ctx.author.voice.channel:
                raise commands.CommandError('Ты хочешь чтобы в голосовом канале было два одинаковых ботов?')
```

При попытке включить это, бот подключается и добавляет её, но не играет(Нету надписи "Играет Сейчас" и в голосовом тоже полная тишина):
[image: Первая]

[image: Вторая]

Бот закинут на хостинг Heroku, вот все билдпаки которые установлены:
[image: BuildPacks]